# Reducing noise between 3 ultrasonic sensors and make Autonomous Robot more precise

Tags: arduino, pid, kalman-filter, ultrasonic-sensors, autonomous-car

I made an autonomous robot with 3 ultrasonic sensors. I want to reduce the noise between the 3 sensors and make it gradually slow when it approaches an obstacle. My code is mentioned below. Please help me in this.

- Distance 1 is front sensor
- Distance 2 is left sensor
- Distance 3 is right sensor.

If you can suggest any  improvements to this code, I would be grateful.

```
//CODE FOR AUTONOMOUS WITH 3 ULTRASONIC SENSORS 
/*code written By 
Faraz Hassan
For Autonomous Rover Obstacle Avoidance */
//include newping and adafruit libraries to the code
#include <NewPing.h>
#include <AFMotor.h>

AF_DCMotor motor1(1);
AF_DCMotor motor2(2);
AF_DCMotor motor3(3);
AF_DCMotor motor4(4);

int trigger_c = A0;          // Controls the pulse sent from the right sensor
int echo_c    = A1;          // Controls the pulse received from the right sensor
int trigger_a = A2;          // Controls the pulse sent from the left sensor
int echo_a    = A3;          // Controls the pulse received from the left sensor
int trigger_b = A4;          // Controls the pulse sent from the front sensor
int echo_b    = A5;          // Controls the pulse received from the front sensor

int tp = 250;//delay

long  duration_b,duration_a, duration_c, distance1, distance2, distance3; 

void setup()
{
// set all the motor control pins to outputs

 Serial.begin(9600);
        pinMode(trigger_b, OUTPUT);    // Arduino signal output from trigger_front
        pinMode(echo_b, INPUT);        // Arduino signal input from echo_front
        pinMode(trigger_a, OUTPUT);    //Arduino signal output from trigger_left
        pinMode(echo_a, INPUT);        // Arduino signal input from echo_left
        pinMode(trigger_c, OUTPUT);    // Arduino signal output from trigger_right
        pinMode(echo_c, INPUT);        //Arduino signal input from echo_right

}

void loop()
{
// Find distance Sonar….
// Clears the trigPin
digitalWrite(trigger_b, LOW);       //Sends a 2 µs LOW signal to the trigPin to make sure it’s turned off at the beginning of the program loop.
delayMicroseconds(2);
// Sets the trigPin on HIGH state for 10 micro seconds
digitalWrite(trigger_b, HIGH);     // Sends a 10 µs HIGH signal to the trigPin to initiate the sequence of eight 40 KHz ultrasonic pulses sent from the transmitting transducer.
delayMicroseconds(10);
digitalWrite(trigger_b, LOW);
// Reads the echoPin, returns the sound wave travel time in microseconds
duration_b= pulseIn(echo_b, HIGH);  //Defines the duration variable as the length (in µs) of any HIGH input
                                    //signal detected at the echoPin. 
                                    //The Echo pin output = time it takes the trigger pin emitted ultrasonic pulse to travel to the object and back to the sensor.
// Calculating the distance
distance1= duration_b*0.034/2;       // Defines the distance variable as the duration (time in d = s x t) multiplied by the speed of sound converted from meters per second to centimeters per µs (0.0344 cm/µs). 
        //(d=s*t) * speed of sound converted from meters per second to centimeters per µs (0.0344 cm/µs).                          
// Prints the distance on the Serial Monitor

Serial.print("front:   ");
Serial.print(distance1);
Serial.print("  ");
Serial.print("left:  ");
Serial.print(distance2);
Serial.print("  ");

Serial.print("right:  ");
Serial.print(distance3);
Serial.println("  ");


// Find distance Sonar2….
// Clears the trigPin
digitalWrite(trigger_a, LOW);
delayMicroseconds(2);
// Sets the trigPin on HIGH state for 10 micro seconds
digitalWrite(trigger_a, HIGH);
delayMicroseconds(10);
digitalWrite(trigger_a, LOW);
// Reads the echoPin, returns the sound wave travel time in microseconds
duration_a = pulseIn(echo_a, HIGH);
// Calculating the distance
distance2= duration_a*0.034/2;
// Prints the distance on the Serial Monitor
digitalWrite(trigger_c, LOW);
delayMicroseconds(2);
// Sets the trigPin on HIGH state for 10 micro seconds
digitalWrite(trigger_c, HIGH);
delayMicroseconds(10);
digitalWrite(trigger_c, LOW);
// Reads the echoPin, returns the sound wave travel time in microseconds
duration_c = pulseIn(echo_c, HIGH);
// Calculating the distance
distance3= duration_c*0.034/2;


motor1.setSpeed(255);
motor2.setSpeed(255);
motor3.setSpeed(255);
motor4.setSpeed(255);
motor1.run(FORWARD);
motor2.run(FORWARD); 
motor3.run(FORWARD);
motor4.run(FORWARD);
 if(Serial.available()>0)//Checking is Serial data available
  {
    int input = Serial.read(); //Storing value of read data into variable assigned
//    switch(input)
//    {
//     case 'o' : forward(); //Calling respective functions if mathced with case label 
//     break;
// 
//     case 'x' : stopMotors();
//     break;
//     default : break;
//    }
  } 
if (distance1 < 28|| distance2 < 28|| distance3 < 28)       //DISTANCE1 FRONT SENSOR  DISTANCE2 LEFT SENSOR  DISTANCE 3 RIGHT SENSOR
{ stopMotors();
delay (1000);
if (distance2 < distance3)   //  LEFT SENSOR DISTANCE < RIGHT SENSOR DISTANCE
{ stopMotors();
   delay (1000);
  turnRight();
delay (700); 
revers();
delay(700);
}
if (distance2 > distance3)  //  LEFT SENSOR DISTANCE >  RIGHT SENSOR DISTANCE
{ stopMotors();
delay (1000);
  turnLeft();
delay (700);
revers();
delay(700);
}
if (distance2 == distance3)  //  LEFT SENSOR DISTANCE ==  RIGHT SENSOR DISTANCE
{ revers();
delay (1000);

}
}

if (distance1 > 28) 
forward();   // FRONT SENSOR  DISTANCE > 25

}

void revers()
{
// turn on motor A
   Serial.println("<Mars Rover> Backward");
motor1.run(BACKWARD);
motor2.run(BACKWARD); 
motor3.run(BACKWARD);
motor4.run(BACKWARD);

 motor1.setSpeed(190);
 motor2.setSpeed(190);
 motor3.setSpeed(190);
  motor4.setSpeed(190);
  delay(tp);
}
void forward()
{
       Serial.println("<Mars Rover> Forward");
       motor1.setSpeed(255);
       motor2.setSpeed(255);
       motor3.setSpeed(255);
       motor4.setSpeed(255);
       motor1.run(FORWARD);
       motor2.run(FORWARD); 
       motor3.run(FORWARD);
       motor4.run(FORWARD);
        delay(tp);

}
void turnRight()
{
  Serial.println("<Mars Rover> Right");
       motor1.setSpeed(255);
       motor2.setSpeed(255);
       motor3.setSpeed(255);
       motor4.setSpeed(255);
       motor1.run(FORWARD);
       motor2.run(FORWARD); 
       motor3.run(BACKWARD);
       motor4.run(BACKWARD);

// Turn period
delay(tp);

}
void turnLeft()
{  Serial.println("<Mars Rover> Left");
       motor1.setSpeed(255);
       motor2.setSpeed(255);
       motor3.setSpeed(255);
       motor4.setSpeed(255);
       motor1.run(BACKWARD);
       motor2.run(BACKWARD); 
       motor3.run(FORWARD);
       motor4.run(FORWARD);

//Turn period
delay(tp);

}
void stopMotors()
{
// Stop motors
  Serial.println("<Mars Rover> Stop");
      motor1.setSpeed(0);
       motor2.setSpeed(0);
       motor3.setSpeed(0);
       motor4.setSpeed(0);
       delay(tp);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues in the question:

1. noise (interference) among the three sensors
2. how to handle the motion with relation to the sensor readings

The noise between sensors is most probably a hardware issue (cabling or EMI) or it might be related to the sensors being close to each other. Without more info about the current implementation, this is all I can say at first thought.

Coming to the motion algorithms:

The current distance to action decisions are based on distinct cases (for example the distances being smaller than a treshold) however gradual motion requires a proportional control mechanism.

Proportional control can be applied to any sensed variable that you want to keep in control. Applying it to the distance variable, you could set up a speed - distance relationship, as follows:

```
d_min_allowed = 10 //the distance that you want the robot to completely stop
d_slowdown_start = 28 //the distance that you want the robot to start slowing down)
distance = (distance1+distance2+distance3)/3   // updated sensor readings

if (distance < d_slowdown_start) {
// start slowdown
error = (distance - d_min_allowed);
motorspeed = Kp*(error);
(Kp=255/ (d_slowdown_start-d_min_allowed) = 255 / 18)
}
```

Once you get this one running, setting up similar proportional control mechanisms for steering will be a joyful challenge.

For more information and background, you can check the following topics online: system control, proportional control, PID control.

Comment: @FarazHassan can you validate it as the answer, so that it will help others find it easily as well.